# How to use webpack for development Angular2 / typescript without running build each time?

Tags: visual-studio, angular, typescript, asp.net-core, webpack

I am using ASP.Net Core, Angular2 and Typescript and connected all together with webpack using the tutorial from Angular2 team [here](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html). That all seems to work but now I need to build each time I change a file.

Original tutorial uses system.js and that loads tons of files of course, but I just use static file middleware and no build is required for development. That is very convinient, but I cannot figure out how to do the same with webpack. It seems that webpack can only bundle everything together without an option to just load everything separately so I need to run the build each time.

Is it possible to do something so that webpack "expands" the bundle in some easy way?

P.S. I would like not to use webpack dev server and some auto-build on save and so on since the complexity is rather high alredy. So ideal solution is that I have bundles for production but direct code loaded for development like in good old days with standard mvc bundling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Really, the best way would be to use webpack dev server. There's really not much setup involved, it's just a different command you run instead of webpack:

```
npm install webpack-dev-server
webpack-dev-server webpack.config.js
```

Then you just point script sources to `http://localhost:8080/webpack-dev-server/your-bundle-name.js" in your application`` tags.

This is by far the best option as you get instant incremental recompile and live-reload.

While I would strongly encourage you to use `webpack-dev-server` you can also just use plain webpack in watch mode:

```
webpack ---watch
```

There is no way to "expand the bundle" (and really no need to). In all likelyhood you are using webapack for more than just bundling, so you'd still require to re-build if you change a typescript file, for example. Webpack dev server or webpack in watch mode do very quick incremental compiles, and most people will just leave them running  while developing.

Comment: If I change a typescript file VS would just recompile it automatically, so that's not a problem at all. But if I have WebApi in the same project e.g., then running webpack dev is not really enough and I would need to run another server, plus somehow reroute all the urls, which is all a little bit of pain I wanted to avoid :) Thanks for the input nontheless, maybe there is no way to do what I want at all.

Comment: Webpack dev server always runs as a separate server that serves just the webpack stuff. I am using  Aspnet mvc and webapi as well, we just have a template for our main index.html which can  load the bundle from the webpack url for dev.

Comment: In any case, "watch" mode in standard webpack should work, you just don't get live-reload and it's slightly slower since it doesn't serve from RAM

Comment: I see, instead of CORS for web-api, you load webpack stuff from you IIS-Express via a <script> tag to the webpack dev server?

Comment: Yeah, you don't need CORS since it is just a `<script>` tag.

Comment: Nice trick, did not think of it that way :) But then the live-reload can't work I suppose? I guess it's something like browser-link for VS and only works if you serve index.html from the same webserver.

Comment: I even have a cookie I can set to dynamically switch it from normal production url back the localhost webpack url. This allows me to debug production issues with a locally running webpack just on my browser.

Comment: That's nice :) Thanks for you help!

Comment: Live reload DOES work if you are using webpack-dev-server. It doesn't load your bundle directly, it has some extra code that uses webscokets to get notified of code changes and automatically reload the page.

Comment: An extra plus  with webpack-dev-server is you will see compilation errors in your browser console.

Comment: I'll try to use it now then, still did not figure out how can dev-server can reload the page that was not even loaded from that server (only scripts were). I guess I'll need to read more about the whole stuff :)